Is resize disabled in converse.js?
The full-screen converse.js client is available from https://conversejs.org/
When I hover my mouse near the left-hand drawer component I get a left-pointing arrow, suggesting that it is interactive.
But, when I try to drag with my mouse text gets selected, rather than the panel being resized.


Macos, Chrome


The fact that you see the resize icon is a bug. In overlayed view mode, the control box (which becomes the left sidebar in fullscreen mode) is resizable, but it's not resizable in fullscreen mode.

Understood.  Thanks @JCBrand
